# numba: parallelize a nested for loop with a cartopy function in it

Tags: python-3.x, numba, cartopy

I am new to numba and trying to understand how it works.

I want to transform the projection of 4D wind vectors from an atmospheric model. The vector dimensions are (time, height, latitude, longitude). Since the cartopy function that re-project the vectors only accept 2D (horizontal) vector fields, I have to loop through the time and height dimensions. Since this is a very large array (of size [48, 90, 1200, 1200]), I am trying to make the nested looping faster using numba without any success. The code doesn't seem to speed up even after using numba and hit the wall time at 2 hours! Is it because numba can't accelerate a cartopy function?

See a cut-down version of my code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy, xarray
from numba import jit, prange

def coord_ref_systems(cube):
     global source_crs, target_crs
     source_crs = ccrs.RotatedPole(pole_longitude=140,
                      pole_latitude=36,
                      globe=ccrs.Globe(semimajor_axis=6370000, semiminor_axis=6370000))
     target_crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

def vector_transform(u, v, lon, lat):
    xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(lon, lat)
    u_t, v_t = target_crs.transform_vectors(source_crs, xx, yy, u, v)
    return u_t, v_t

@jit(parallel=True)
def transformer(u, v, lon, lat):
    u_new, v_new = numpy.empty(u.shape), numpy.empty(u.shape)
    for ti in prange(len(u.shape[0])):
        for zi in prange(len(u.shape[1])):
            u_t, v_t = vector_transform(u[ti, zi, :, :].squeeze(), v[ti, zi, :, :].squeeze(), lon, lat)
            u_new[ti, zi, :, :] = u_t
            v_new[ti, zi, :, :] = v_t
    return u_new, v_new

def main():
    ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('wind_vectors.nc', chunks={'time':6, 'height':-1, 'latitude': 200, 'longitude': 200})
    u = ds['U']
    v = ds['V']
    _u_, _v_ = transformer(u.values, v.values, u.longitude.values, u.latitude.values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your intuition is correct about Numba not being able to speed up external libraries like Cartopy. If you replace `jit` with `njit` (or add the `nopython=True`) keyword you should get an error explaining that. For fast coordinate transformation you might be better of doing that upfront (separate from visualization/cartopy) using something like pyproj. Pyproj takes arrays as input so it would probably be as fast as it gets for large arrays.

Comment: See [Will Numba work for my code?](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#will-numba-work-for-my-code) (this is the first page of the doc but it is generally not read by people using Numba...)